# AEM Site search query builder URL is not returning a different json

Tags: adobe, aem, query-builder, aem-6, aem-63

Am using AEM Site search component from core components. query builder URL is not returning a different json.
Once after searching with a text, am getting a json. Thereafter doing any search with new search text, am getting only the same json, not a new json. Only old response am getting in all search.

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (self._hasMoreResults) {

```
        var response;
        
        var url = self._action + "?" + serialize(self._elements.form) + "&" + PARAM_RESULTS_OFFSET + "=" + self._resultsOffset;
        request.open("GET", url, true);
```

request.onload = function() {

```
            setTimeout(function() {
                toggleShow(self._elements.loadingIndicator, false);
                toggleShow(self._elements.icon, true);
            }, LOADING_DISPLAY_DELAY);
           
                if (request.status == 200 ) {
                debugger;
                
                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                 if (data.length > 0) {
                    self._generateItems(data, self._elements.results);
                    self._markResults();
                    toggleShow(self._elements.results, true);
                } else {
                    self._hasMoreResults = false;
                }
                
                if (self._elements.results.querySelectorAll(selectors.item.self).length % self._properties.resultsSize > 0) {
                    self._hasMoreResults = false;
                }
            } else {
                // error status
            }
        };
        
        toggleShow(self._elements.loadingIndicator, true);
        toggleShow(self._elements.icon, false);
        request.send('');
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you find the root cause?

Comment: In my case, the json is been cached at cloud. Hence this can be resoled.